# Conflicting declaration of function with ‘C’ linkage

Tags: c++

Following compiles without error:

```cpp
extern "C" void func( void );
extern void func( void );
```

If I change order of declarations,

```cpp
extern void func( void );
extern "C" void func( void );
```

I get compiler error: `conflicting declaration of ‘void func()’ with ‘C’ linkage`.
C++ standard says:

- At most one function with a particular name can have "C" linkage (regardless of namespace)

In both cases it is the same function. My assumption is that C++ compiler stores internally functions signature it will compile. In first example, compiler consideres second declaration as valid and uses first declaration to compile. In second example it is not the case. It regrads both declarations as diferent declaration.
What are technical details behind it?
gcc 9.4.0 and msvc 19.29.30147

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: Ideally they should all have the same signature. Why the differences? Can't this be defined in a header file which both instances can reference?

Comment: Why do you need one `func` with C++ linkage at all?

Comment: @tadman A second one w/o `extern "C"` is allowed because it's an option for an implementation in .c, where `extern "C"` is not valid.

Comment: @273K I'm not saying it's not allowed, but it is inconsistent, and that's the first step on the road to problems like this. If that's being built in a C context you're right, that will be trouble, but that could be addressed with some `#ifdef` magic in the singular header file that defines this.

Comment: The first `extern` declaration encountered determines linkage; you can't change the linkage after the initial declaration.

Comment: That is, the first is equivalent to `extern "C" void func( void ); extern "C" void func( void );`, the second to `extern "C++" void func( void ); extern "C" void func( void );`

Comment: I would like to understand what causes error, not how it shouldbe done. I am very well aware how it should be done. This is C++ compiler wunderstending question. Not how it should be done or what do you not understand. I clearly said: I do not understand why changing order of two declaration causes compilker error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-declarations of a function are not required to repeat their linkage specification. Per [Language linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) from cppreference:

> A function can be re-declared without a linkage specification after it was declared with a language specification, the second declaration will reuse the first language linkage. The opposite is not true: if the first declaration has no language linkage, it is assumed `"C++"`, and redeclare with another language is an error.

In the first snippet, you declare a function with `"C"` linkage and then later re-declare it with no explicit linkage. This is okay; the original linkage is assumed. However, in the second snippet, you declare a function with (implicit) `"C++"` linkage, and then later attempt to re-declare it with `"C"` linkage---that's a conflict, hence the error.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Part of cpp reference which explains why order of declaration is important. Answer is in 'The opposite is not true:'