# Gem seven_zip_ruby fails compiling extensions on 3.0.2 alpine based image but not on 3.0.2 debian based one

Tags: c, ruby, alpine-linux

I've encountered an error but I can't figure out how to fix it.

My application uses the seven_zip_ruby gem and is based on a ruby:3.0.2-alpine image. When I try to install the gem on a Debian image, everything works fine but when I try to install it on an Alpine-based image I get a compilation error.

[seven_zip_ruby](https://github.com/masamitsu-murase/seven_zip_ruby) fails to compile native extensions on docker alpine-based images but not on Debian-based images

Error is the following:

```
"gcc -I/usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0/aarch64-linux-musl -I/usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I.    -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wduplicated-cond -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wimplicit-fallthrough=0 -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wunused-variable  -fPIC  -std=c++0x -x c++  -c conftest.c"
cc1plus: warning: command-line option '-Wimplicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command-line option '-Wimplicit-int' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby.h:38,
                 from conftest.c:1:
/usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/memory.h:276:16: error: conflicting declaration of 'void* ruby_nonempty_memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' with 'C' linkage
  276 | #define memcpy ruby_nonempty_memcpy
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/memory.h:266:1: note: previous declaration with 'C++' linkage
  266 | ruby_nonempty_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option '-Wno-self-assign' may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option '-Wno-parentheses-equality' may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option '-Wno-constant-logical-operand' may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <functional>
 4: #include <algorithm>
 5: #include <array>
 6: #include <iostream>
 7: 
 8: #include <ruby.h>
 9: 
10: // see the test on memset_s below, which is a purely BSD thing
11: #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(BSD)
12: #include <string.h>
13: #endif
14: 
15: void test()
16: {
17:     int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
18:     const int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
19:     std::array<int, size> var_list;
20: 
21:     std::function<int (int, int)> convert = [&](int arg1, int arg2){
22:         return arg1 * arg2;
23:     };
24: 
25:     const int value = 10;
26: 
27:     std::transform(array, array + size, var_list.begin(), [&](int arg){
28:         return convert(arg, value);
29:     });
30: 
31:     std::for_each(var_list.begin(), var_list.end(), [](int num){ std::cout << num << std::endl; });
32: 
33: #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(BSD)
34:     char str[] = "imareallycoolstringright";
35:     memset_s(str, sizeof str, 'b', 5);
36: #endif
37: }
/* end */
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

A repository with a reproducible error can be found here: [repository](https://github.com/armandfardeau/seven_zip_ruby_docker)

gcc info on debian based image:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
```

gcc info on alpine based image:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-alpine-linux-musl
Configured with: /home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-10.3.1_git20210424/configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=aarch64-alpine-linux-musl --host=aarch64-alpine-linux-musl --target=aarch64-alpine-linux-musl --with-pkgversion='Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424' --enable-checking=release --disable-fixed-point --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cloog-backend --enable-languages=c,c++,d,objc,go,fortran,ada --with-arch=armv8-a --with-abi=lp64 --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libmpx --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424)

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-alpine-linux-musl
Configured with: /home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-10.3.1_git20210424/configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=aarch64-alpine-linux-musl --host=aarch64-alpine-linux-musl --target=aarch64-alpine-linux-musl --with-pkgversion='Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424' --enable-checking=release --disable-fixed-point --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cloog-backend --enable-languages=c,c++,d,objc,go,fortran,ada --with-arch=armv8-a --with-abi=lp64 --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libmpx --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424)
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438483/conflicting-declaration-of-function-with-c-linkage) the error is explained; But you are not an author of ruby libraries ofc, so the issue seems to be ruby version. In [current master](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/include/ruby/internal/memory.h) it looks OK, and in your version there is probably some hidden `extern "C"` after the first declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I cannot upgrade this dependency right now. Do you have an idea of a flag I can use to make the compiling work as in the Debian-based image?

Comment: No clue, you can try to apply some quick-hacks by hand, like removing the export macros, or changing the declaration order. But it's not guaranteed to work without recompiling ruby library. You can also try to ask the authors directly.